# Cutting substrings in Haskell

Tags: strings, haskell

How can I improve readability of this code? `indentChar` needs to be reused elsewhere.

```
toCoordinate = dropWhile ((||) <$> (not . indentChar) <*> (=='(')) >>> takeWhile(/= ' ')
indentChar = (||) <$> isAlpha <*> (=='(')
```

Desired result:

```
*Parse> toCoordinate " \\--(my.coordinate - from outerspace)"
"my.coordinate"
```

Comment: It would help to know what your input format is supposed to be. It looks pretty arbitrary, does `"\\--"` actually mean anything or are those completely arbitrary characters? Is the coordinate text, or will it really be comprised of digits? Also, you have mismatched parentheses in the definition of `toCoordinate`.

Comment: I find `indentChar = liftA2 (||) isAlpha (=='(')` more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I observe is that the `dropWhile` function argument is:

`\x -> (not . indentChar) x || '(' == x`

The comparison to '(' cancels out that same comparison in indentChar -- so the following definition of toCoordinate is identical in meaning:

`toCoordinate = dropWhile (not . isAlpha) >>> takeWhile (/= ' ')`

You did state that you need to use indentChar elsewhere -- but *not* using it here makes your code clearer.

Additionally, rather than use arrows, the above definition seems clearer to me when using function composition -- I would write it as:

`toCoordinate = takeWhile (/= ' ') . dropWhile (not . isAlpha)`